# Remove/Hide Quantity Option in Paypal Summary Section

Tags: php, paypal

I'm building a website in which we don't need that quantity tab in Paypal. Is there any way to remove or hide that option?

please see the image below for better understanding

[image]

the fields I'm sending is

```
$p->add_field('business', 'testaccount@gmail.com');
$p->add_field('return', $success_script);
$p->add_field('currency_code','GBP');
$p->add_field('cancel_return', $cancel_script);
$p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
$p->add_field('item_name', "Title: ".$pakage_name);
$p->add_field('amount', $price);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the "Quantity: 1" , find the "Quantity:" in the php file.( I hope a variable is passing here that has returned from database. )
you can simply comment PHP and html sections.
If this answer is not enough you have to show few lines of the code to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, in this case. PayPal seems to insist on quantity being a value of 1 or more. Look at the note screenshot [from their docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). Yes it's optional to pass quantity, but it can never be less than 1.

[image]